# Does continuous crawl remove deleted items

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results, crawl, content-source

I have a problem with the Search results. I removed a few pages but these pages will stay in the search results.

On the Farm i run a continuous crawl without any full crawl. Is the continuous crawl suppose to remove deleted items from the search results?

Comment: In my experience deletions are not processed in continuous crawl. They are handled in incremental and/or full crawl. I don't have any documentation, but that is what we've seen in two years of using cross-site publishing. What we do is use publishing features and first mark as rejected/unpublished. That is picked up by the continuous and the item is then "hidden" after that it is deleted and will eventually be removed by incremental or full.

Comment: Soon if the problem is solved i can you give an answer to that

Answer (score 2):

Ok i found the problem why the deleted item was still in the index

We changed the settings of the following:

```
$SearchApplication = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Identity "Search Service Application"
$SearchApplication.SetProperty("ErrorDeleteCountAllowed", 1)
$SearchApplication.SetProperty("ErrorDeleteIntervalAllowed",0)
```

mentioned in this post: [Deleted item still showing up in search results if only doing Incremental Crawls](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75336/deleted-item-still-showing-up-in-search-results-if-only-doing-incremental-crawls)

Only we didn't set them to 1 and 0, I set it to: 10 and 240.

Both properties needs to be true before removed from the index. 10 Crawls and 240 hours before it is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

A continuous crawl crawls content that was added, changed, or deleted since the last crawl.

But it highly advice able to run the full crawl( some recommend run Incremental daily) in a while to keep refresh and healthy your index. There is one disadvantage about Continuous crawl does not process or retry items that return errors more than three times.

Read more here: [Manage continuous crawls in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219802.aspx)

Comment: but what is the reason that i keep dead links in the search results. He doesn't seems to see that the page is removed or something

Comment: what you mean the dead links? if item is deleted than continous crawl will remove it but for some reason that item/link throws the error then it will not be picked by CC, reason CC dont have ability to retry and you need incremental / full crawl to fix those errors.

Comment: Ok but it says still a green dot so i can assume that it doesn't have a error right:)